# What does the phrase 'without exception' mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

In this following context, what does the phrase 'without exception' mean?

Does it add for emphasis only?

Context:

> If whatever we have seen, heard, felt, perceived, thought, experienced
> and done were not, without exception, registered somewhere and in some
> way, either in the extremely complex nervous system (comparable to a
> phonograph record or photographic plate) or in the subconscious or
> unconscious, we would not even be able to remember what we were
> thinking at the preceding moment;

Source: Fundamentals of Buddhism, Four Lectures by Nyanatiloka Mahathera

Comment: It means the same as 'always', but is perhaps stronger and more emphatic.

Comment: Whatever the dictionary definition of 'exception' is - it's the complete absence of that.

Comment: Are you maybe struggling to parse the text because of that formal / stilted use of "subjunctive" ***were***? You might find it more comprehensible if you think of it as ***If** [everything we see] ... **wasn't** (without exception) registered somewhere [**then** things would be different].*

Comment: First, the text is a translation. Second, those terms will be in any bilingual dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

‘Without exception’ means ‘Always true’. ‘Exception’ means ‘A case where (something) is not true’, so the original phrase means ‘With no cases of (something) being not true’.

Answer (score 0):

"Without exception" means that there are no cases where this is not true.

Sometimes we use "absolute" words but we really don't mean them absolutely. Like if I say, "Sally always gets to work on time", maybe I mean literally, 100% of the time. But often people make such statements meaning 99+% of the time. If Sally was late to work once in the past 20 years, then "always" would not be literally true, but it would not be surprising if her boss or co-workers said that, even if they knew about that one exception.

There are times when people use absolute words as a deliberate exaggeration. Like if someone says, "You always lie!", they probably do not mean that literally 100% of the statements you make are false, but rather that you lie very frequently.

So to make clear that we really mean an absolute word literally, we have to add some additional qualifiers. One way to do this is to say "without exception". Like, "Sally is always on time for work, every day without exception for the past 20 years." (There are many other ways one might clarify this.)

I'm suddenly reminded of a statement I read once about a politician, a critic said, "Every word he says is a lie. Including 'of' and 'the'."